# Display VF page content into Excel File - doesn't display all contents in excel file

Tags: visualforce, excel

I have written a code to display the VF page into an excel file on button click. When button is clicked the excel file gets downloaded but it doesn't display all the related list fields like Case Comments, Email messages, Sales Order etc.

Below is my page:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="case" extensions="PNcCase,CaseHistoryCon,CaseRelaredList" contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#{!caseobj.casenumber}.xls" standardstylesheets="false" cache="true">

  <!-- <chatter:feedWithFollowers entityId="{!case.id}"/>-->
   <apex:form >  
        <script type="text/javascript">
  function Callmefunc(id)
  {

      var type = document.getElementById(id).value;
      check(type); 
  }
  </script>       
       <style type="text/css">
      
       </style>
           <apex:pageMessages id="msgs"/> 
                  
           <apex:pageBlock title="Case Number : {!caseObj.CaseNumber}" id="pgBlock">
                   <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showSpecialInstructionPane}" id="instructions">
                       <div  Style="display:block;  border: 1px solid #7FD2F5; text-align: left; background-color: #CC0000; padding-top: 5px; padding-bottom: 5px; color: #FFFFFF; font-size: 10pt; font-weight: normal; font-family: Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;">       
                           <apex:outputfield value="{!contactObj.Account.Special_Instructions__c}"/>      
                       </div> 
                   </apex:outputPanel>
  
               
               <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0"   style="table-layout:fixed;word-wrap: break-word;background-color:white;"> 
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Contact</b>
                           <br/> 
                              
                           <apex:inputField style="width:200px" value="{!caseObj.contactid}"/>
                                 
                           <br/>
                       </td>  
                <!-- Added End Customer Field as per Dirk Email 15-Jul-2017-->
                      <td  class = "block"><b>End Customer</b>
                          <br/> 
                               <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.End_Customer__c}" style="width:200px" Required="True" />                                    
                          <br/>
                       </td>  
                   <!--End-->

                                 
                       <td  class = "block"><b>Severity</b>
                           <br/> 
                               <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Severity__c}"  required="{!isRequired}" style="width:200px"  rendered="{!whycallingfield}" />                                    
                           <br/>
                       </td>               
                       <td  class = "block"><b>Case Title</b>
                           <br/> 
                                <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Subject}"  style="width:200px"  required="{!isRequired}"  />                                 
                           <br/>
                       </td> 
                   </tr> 
               
                   
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Last Name</b>
                           <br/> 
                                   <apex:outputField value="{!contactObj.LastName}" id="LastName" style="width:200px">
                                  <script>document.getElementById('{!$Component.contactObj.LastName}').disabled = "true"; </script> 
                                         
                                       </apex:outputField>
                           <br/>
                       </td>  
                      <td  class = "block"><b>Customer Environment</b>
                      <br/> 
                               <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.customer_environment__c}" style="width:200px" Required="True" />                                    
                          <br/>
                       </td>   
                                  
                       <td  class = "block"><b>Priority</b>
                       <br/> 
                               <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Priority}"  required="true" style="width:200px"  rendered="{!whycallingfield}" />                                   
                           <br/>
                       </td>               
                       <td  class = "block"><b>Next Action</b>
                       <br/> 
                                <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Next_Action__c}" style="width:200px;length:100px;" />                                
                           <br/>
                       </td>       
                   </tr> 
                   
                   
                   
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>First Name</b>
                       <br/> 
                               <apex:outputField value="{!contactObj.FirstName}" id="FirstName" style="width:200px" ></apex:outputField>
                               <br/>
                       </td>   
                       <td  class = "block"><b>Hotfix Required?</b>
                       <br/> 
                                <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Hotfix_required__c}" style="width:200px"  rendered="{!whycallingfield}" />     
                                    <br/><br/>
                            <b>Case Keyword</b>
                                    <br/>
                                    <apex:inputTextArea value="{!caseObj.Case_keyword__c}" style="width:200px" rows="4"  rendered="{!whycallingfield}" />
                                     <br/>
                                    
                                        </td>  
                             
                           <td  class = "block"><b>Bug#</b>
                           <br/> 
                                   <apex:inputField Value="{!caseObj.Bug__c}" style="width:200px"/>
                            
                           <br/>
                       </td>                        
                       
                       <td  class = "td" ><b>Work-Around</b>
                       <br/> 
                                    <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Work_Around__c}" style="width:200px"  />
                           <br/>
                       </td> 
                   </tr> 
                   
                   </tr> 
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Site Account </b>
                       <br/> 
                              
                           <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Site__c}"  id="siteaccount" style="width:200px" rendered="{!whycallingfield}"  />  
                                    
                               
                           <br/>
                       </td> 
 
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Partner Owns Case</b>
                       <br/> 
                               <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Partner_Owns_Case__c}" style="width:200px" rendered="{!whycallingfield}"/>                             
                           <br/>
                       </td>
                      
                            
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Days Open</b>
                       <br/> 
                                <apex:outputfield value="{!caseObj.Days_Open__c}" />           
                           <br/>
                       </td>                                                      
      
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Last Modified Date</b>
                       <br/> 
                                <apex:outputfield value="{!caseObj.LastModifieddate}" />           
                           <br/>
                       </td> 
                   </tr>
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Partner Contact</b>
                       <br/> 
                                            
                           <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Partner_Contact__c}" style="width:200px" rendered="{!whycallingfield}"/> 
                                                           
                           <br/>
                       </td>   
                       <td  class = ""><b>Category 1</b>
                       <br/>                                
                                <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Category_1__c}" id="category" style="width:200px" rendered="{!whycallingfield}"></apex:inputField>
                           <br/>
                       </td>
                          <td  class = "td"><b>Service Contract</b>
                          <br/> 
                               
                                           <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput">
                                   <apex:outputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredBlock" rendered="{!isRequired}"/>
                                   <apex:actionRegion >
                                       <apex:selectList value="{!serviceContractList}"  size="1" id="entitlement" style="width:200px" >
                                           <apex:selectOptions value="{!ServiceContractLineItemList}"/>
                                           <apex:actionsupport id="serContact" event="onchange" action="{!getLoadAssets}" rerender="assetOutPan"  />
                                       <!--    <apex:actionsupport event="onchange"  action="{!verifyEntitlementStatus}" rerender="entitlementstatus,active,inactive"></apex:actionsupport> -->
                                       </apex:selectList>         
                                   </apex:actionRegion>
                                </apex:outputPanel>
                               <apex:outputpanel id="entitlementstatus">    
                                   
                               <!--    <apex:image id="active" value="https://cs15.salesforce.com/img/entitlement/active_entitlement_status.png"  rendered="{!entitlementflag}"/>
                                   <apex:image id="inactive" value="https://cs15.salesforce.com/img/entitlement/expired_entitlement_status.png" rendered="{!!entitlementflag}"/> -->
                           
                               </apex:outputpanel>                         
                              <br/>
                       </td>                                                     
                                           
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Created By</b>
                       <br/> 
                                <apex:OutputField value="{!caseObj.createdbyId}" id="createdbyId" style="width:200px"></apex:OutputField>                      
                           <br/>
                       </td>         

                   </tr>
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Partner Phone</b>
                       <br/> 
                                <apex:outputField value="{!partnerContact.phone}" style="width:200px"  id="partnerphone" />
                           <br/>
                       </td>            
                               <td  class = "td"><b>Category 2</b>
                               <br/> 
                                 <apex:inputField value="{!CaseObj.Category_2__c}" id="category2" style="width:200px" rendered="{!whycallingfield}" ></apex:inputField>
                                   <br/>
                       </td>               
                      <td  class = "td"><b>Regression </b>
                      <br/> 
                                 <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Regression__c}" style="width:200px"  rendered="{!whycallingfield}"/>
                          <br/>
                       </td>      
                   </tr>
                   
                   
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Partner Email</b>
                       <br/> 
                               <apex:outputField value="{!partnerContact.email}" style="width:200px"  id="partneremail" ></apex:outputField>
                           <br/>
                       </td>            
                       <td  class = "td"><b>POC </b>
                       <br/> 
                                   <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.POC__c}" style="width:200px" id="POC" rendered="{!whycallingfield}" />    
                           <br/>
                       </td>  
                        <td  class = "td"><b> CU Driven</b>
                           <br/>                               
                           <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.CU_Driven__c}" style="width:230px" rendered="{!whycallingfield}"/> 
                       </td>                                                              
                       <td  class = "td"><b> </b>
                       <br/> 
                                
                           <br/>
                       </td>               
                       <td  class = "td"><b></b>
                       <br/> 
                                           
                           <br/>
                       </td> 
                   </tr>
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   
                   <tr  class = "label"> 
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Partner Case #</b>
                       <br/> 
                               <apex:inputField value="{!caseObj.Partner_Case__c}" id="partnerCase" style="width:200px" rendered="{!whycallingfield}"></apex:inputField>
                           <br/>
                       </td>            
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Date/Time Engineer Assigned </b>
                       <br/>                                
                           <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.Date_Time_Engineer_Assigned__c}"/>
                            <br/>
                       </td>             
                       <td  class = "td"><b>Date/Time Initial Response</b>
                       <br/>
                           <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.Date_Time_Initial_Response__c}"/>
                           <br/>
                       </td>
                        <td  class = "td"><b>Date/Time Initial Mitigation Provided</b>
                       <br/> 
                           <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.Date_Time_Initial_Mitigation_Provided__c}"/>
                           <br/>
                       </td>  
             
                       <!--
                       <td  class = "td"><b></b>
                       <br/> 
                                           
                           <br/>
                       </td>
                       -->
                       <!-- Edited By Magesh-->
                      <!-- <td  class = "td" style="background:yellow;"><b>Serial Number</b>
                           <br> 
                               <apex:outputPanel layout="block" id="assetOutPan1">
                                   <apex:outputPanel layout="block"/>
                                   <apex:actionRegion >
                                   <apex:selectList value="{!selectedasset}"  size="1" id="asset1" style="width:200px" label="Serial Number" >
                                       <apex:selectOptions value="{!assetListOpts}"/>
                                   </apex:selectList>            
                               </apex:actionRegion>
                           </apex:outputPanel>                         
                                       <br/>
                       </td>-->
                   </tr>
                   

               </table>
      
   </apex:pageBlock>                                      
</apex:form>   

<!-- CASE COMMENTS -->
      
      <apex:pageBlock >  
       <apex:pageblockSection title="Case Comments" columns="1">
            <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align:center" id="pnCasecommentbtn">
     
            <apex:form >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Add Comment" action="{!Addcomment}" style="background:none"/>                
                </apex:form> 
                
                </apex:outputPanel>
           
                       <apex:dataTable var="Comment" value="{!CasecommentList}" id="CommentList" style="border: 0px Solid Blue;" >
                                                         <!--  <apex:facet name="header">Case Comment</apex:facet>-->
                                      
                                        <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Action</apex:facet>  
                                      <apex:outputLink value="/{!Comment.Id + editURL}" >Edit</apex:outputLink>             
                                      </apex:column>
                                       <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Public</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!Comment.IsPublished}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                                       <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Created Date</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!Comment.CreatedDate}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                                       
                                       <apex:column style="white-space:wrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Comment</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!Comment.CommentBody}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                                       
                                                                            
                                        <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Created By</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!Comment.CreatedById}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                                       
                                       <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Last Modified By</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!Comment.LastModifiedDate}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                               
                       </apex:dataTable>
                       
                       </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>

<!--Sales Order  List-->
<apex:pageBlock >  
   <apex:pageblockSection title="Sales Orders" columns="1">

                       <apex:pageBlockTable var="SalesOrder" value="{!SalesOrdertList}" id="SalesOrderlist" >                        
                                   <apex:column width="80px"  >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Sales Order Name</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputLink value="/{!SalesOrder.Id }" >{!SalesOrder.Name}</apex:outputLink>             
                                      </apex:column>
                                       <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Record Type</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!SalesOrder.RecordType.Name}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                                       <apex:column width="80px" headerValue="Status" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!SalesOrder.Status__c}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                                       <apex:column style="white-space:wrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">RMA #</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!SalesOrder.RMA__c}"/>  
                                       </apex:column>
                                       
                                      <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                                      <apex:facet name="header">Type</apex:facet>
                                      <apex:outputField value="{!SalesOrder.Type__c}"/>  
                                      </apex:column>
                       </apex:pageblockTable>

                       </apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageBlock >
      
               
      
         
         <apex:pageblockSection title="Email Messages" columns="1">
         
        <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align:center" id="pnlEmailButton">
    
     
         </apex:outputPanel>
       <apex:dataTable var="Emaillist" value="{!CaseEmailList}">
            <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:wrap;" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Subject</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!Emaillist.Subject}"/>
                  
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Email From</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!Emaillist.FromName}"/>  
           </apex:column>
            <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:wrap;" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">To Address</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!Emaillist.ToAddress}"/>  
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Is Incoming</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!Emaillist.Incoming}"/>  
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Email Status</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!Emaillist.Status}"/>  
           </apex:column>
           <apex:column width="80px" style="white-space:nowrap;" >
                  <apex:facet name="header">Email Date</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!Emaillist.MessageDate}"/>  
           </apex:column>
     
</apex:dataTable>
</apex:pageblockSection>
</apex:pageBlock>


<apex:pageBlock id="relatedList">
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Open Activities" columns="1">
   <apex:relatedList list="OpenActivities" ></apex:relatedList>
</apex:pageBlockSection>


<apex:pageBlockSection title="knowledge Base"  columns="1" rendered="{!loggedInUser.UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser}">
   <apex:relatedList list="CaseArticles" ></apex:relatedList>
</apex:pageBlockSection>


  
   
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Next action History"  columns="1">
  <apex:relatedList list="Case_Historys1__r"   subject="{!Case}" title="Next action History" rendered="{!$ObjectType.Case_History__c.accessible}"></apex:relatedList> 
</apex:pageBlockSection> 
   
   
   
   
 
<!--<apex:pageBlockSection title="Sales Order"  columns="1">
   <apex:relatedList list="Sales_Order__c" subject="{!Case}"></apex:relatedList>
</apex:pageBlockSection>-->

</apex:pageBlock>

<apex:pageBlock id="thePageBlock">
          
               <apex:pageBlockSection title="Case History Details" columns="1">
               
                   <apex:outputPanel layout="block" style="text-align:center"/>
             
               <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!histories}" var="h" width="100%">
                   <apex:column width="150px" headerValue="Date"  value="{!h.historyDate}"/>
                   <apex:column width="80px" headerValue="Who"  value="{!h.actorname}"/>
                   <apex:column width="80px" headerValue="What" value="{!h.historyType}"/>
                   <apex:column width="80px" headerValue="From" value="{!h.fr}"/>
                   <apex:column width="80px" headerValue="To" value="{!h.to}"/>
               </apex:pageBlockTable>
               </apex:pageBlocksection>
               </apex:pageBlock>
      
     <apex:pageBlock >
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Activity History"  columns="1" >            
    <apex:relatedList list="ActivityHistories" subject="{!Case}"></apex:relatedList>   
 <apex:pageBlockSection title="SLA History"  columns="1">
  <apex:relatedList list="Case_Priority_Interval_Trackings__r" subject="{!Case}"  rendered="{!$ObjectType.Case_Priority_Interval_Tracking__c.accessible}"></apex:relatedList> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>  
    </apex:pageBlocksection>  
  </apex:pageBlock> 

    
<apex:pageBlock >

<apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Survey Details"> 
         
           <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.css_csat_v1_0__Is_Survey_Mail_Sent__c}" />   
           <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.css_csat_v1_0__Reason__c}" />
           <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.css_csat_v1_0__Survey_Sent_Date__c}" />
           <apex:outputField value="{!caseObj.css_csat_v1_0__Survey_Received_Date__c}" />
        
       </apex:pageBlocksection>  
  </apex:pageBlock>          
</apex:page>
```

Please help me with the issue..

Answer (score 4):

Setting the `contentType` property of a Visualforce page does not perform any conversion of the data. Your page is still rendered as HTML; the server simply *claims* it is an Excel sheet, which is not true.

In some select circumstances, Excel will interpret HTML tables as if they were in fact spreadsheets. But much of your page is not a table: you are using standard components like buttons and related lists. There is absolutely no guarantee, nor even reason to suppose, that those components will render into HTML that Excel will choose to interpret as tabular spreadsheet data.

If you need document generation, you should consider purchasing an AppExchange application that handles the relevant file formats natively. Otherwise, you'll have to invest significantly more work to render the desired data in tabular HTML, but you'll always be doing something that is at best semi-supported.

Comment: Thanks David!
Can you please help me with any work-around for this? or any modifications in the code?

Comment: This is not something you can "work around". You need to fundamentally rethink the approach and consider how to complete it.